# Find and exec: deal with filenames that contain apostrophes

Tags: bash, find

I have the following script to batch encrypt files:

```
#!/bin/bash
find "/some/dir" -type f -exec bash -c "gpg -e -r some_email@gmail.com '{}' && rm '{}'" \;
```

The script works fine except when the filename contains an apostrophe. Then gpg prints an error about improper syntax. How to deal with these files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this could also be done without invoking the shell at all:

```
find "/some/dir" -type f -exec gpg -e -r some_email@gmail.com {} \; -exec rm {} \;
```

or

```
find "/some/dir" -type f -exec gpg -e -r some_email@gmail.com {} \; -delete
```

That should work since `-exec ... \;` also acts as a conditional, so if `gpg` fails, the following `-exec` or `-delete` would not run.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `{}` to embed the filename in the middle of the shell code, pass it as an argument to the shell.

Like this:

```
find "/some/dir" -type f -exec bash -c '
    gpg -e -r some_email@gmail.com "$1" && echo rm "$1"
' bash {} \;
```

Remove `echo` statement when the output is satisfactory.

---

IMHO it's a very interesting concept, not only for this special case, this is a trick to have in the toolbox ;)